# Unix sendmail - html embed image not working

Tags: html, unix, base64, embed

With the prior posts in SO.com I have tried building my script to send email to my Outlook account with the Image inline in the email body. But the html contents are getting displayed in the html rather displaying the image. Please help.

Here is my snippet

```
{
echo "TO: XXX@YYY.com"
echo "FROM: TEST_IMAGE@YYY.com>"
echo "SUBJECT: Embed image test"
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
echo "Content-Type: multipart/related;boundary="--XYZ""

echo "--XYZ"
echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15"
echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit"
echo "<html>"
echo "<head>"
echo "<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15">"
echo "</head>"
echo "<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000">"
echo "<img src="cid:part1.06090408.01060107" alt="">"
echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"


echo "--XYZ"
echo "Content-Type: image/jpeg;name="sathy.jpg""
echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
echo "Content-ID: <part1.06090408.01060107>"
echo "Content-Disposition: inline; filename="sathy.jpg""
echo $(base64 sathy.jpg)
echo "' />"
echo "--XYZ--"
}| /usr/lib/sendmail -t
```

Email I received contains the below rather displaying the image,

```
--XYZ
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=content-type content=text/html
</head>
<body bgcolor=#ffffff text=#000000>
<img src=cid:part1.06090408.01060107 alt=>
</body>
</html>
--XYZ
Content-Type: image/jpeg;name=sathy.jpg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <part1.06090408.01060107>
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=sathy.jpg
/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/sABFEdWNreQABAAQAAAAoAAD/4QNxaHR0cDov
....base64 values.....
/>
--XYZ--
----XYZ--
```

Can you please assist me in what am i missing

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The way you use `echo` to print the message headers it eats all double quotes - you need to escape them with a backslash (`\"`) to make it work.

Also, your boundary is wrong. If you define `boundary=--XYZ`, then each message part needs to start with `----XYZ` (you need to *add* two dashes), otherwise your boundary should be only `XYZ`. And the headers of the mime parts must be separated from the bodies by an empty line.

If you really need to generate a mail from a shell script, then my advise would be to get rid of all the echo and use a heredoc instead:

```
sendmail -t <<EOT
TO: XXX@YYY.com
FROM: <TEST_IMAGE@YYY.com>
SUBJECT: Embed image test
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related;boundary="XYZ"

--XYZ
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000">
<img src="cid:part1.06090408.01060107" alt="">
</body>
</html>

--XYZ
Content-Type: image/jpeg;name="sathy.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <part1.06090408.01060107>
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="sathy.jpg"

$(base64 sathy.jpg)
--XYZ--
EOT
```

Comment: 1/0 thanks to you. So clear and detailed explanation. You rock!!

Comment: Awesome response! This also worked for me with regular `mail`, using `mail -r "<test_image@YYY.com>" -s "Embed image test" -a "MIME-Version: 1.0" -a "Content-Type: multipart/related;boundary=\"XYZ\"" XXX@YYY.com <<EOT` and then starting the heredoc with `--XYZ` and everything that follows.

Comment: How to extend this function to use multiple images?

Comment: @sugunan. you add another <img src> in the <body> and appropriate img definition section