# Old sendmail with Perl need to embed attachment

Tags: perl, embed

Before someone says I need to use MIME::Lite or another pm...  My job has a BASE set of pms and I can't change them...  I really need help working within the confines of my system:

We have been using this code to send email to our clients for years:

```
open MAIL, "| /usr/lib/sendmail -t";
print MAIL qq[To: $email
From: MyFooFoo\@www.foobar.com
Reply-to: do not reply
Subject: This is the subject

Hello, this is the body of the message

Thank you

];
close MAIL;
```

Now, they are asking me to EMBED an image in the email...  I have tried to use [Unix sendmail - html embed image not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973076/unix-sendmail-html-embed-image-not-working) as a reference, but I can't figure out the boundary/mime types...

Comment: Even if you can't use a module in your production system, you can still use the module by examining its source and learning how it implements the functionality you desire.  Alternatively, even if you don't want to spend time learning from the source, you can observe the resulting email and try to duplicate it.  And perhaps you'll be inspired to figure out another way to bring in more modules to ease the development process, like `local::lib`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to build your mail as a MIME message with multipart/related and then feed it to sendmail. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2110, it contains examples of how such mail looks like and how to embed images into HTML mail etc. You probably need a way to base64 encode data, but either you can use MIME::Base64 for it, an external command line tool or program it yourself in just a few lines (see source of MIME::Base64).

Comment: Thanks Steffen, I tried this, but wasn't able to get it to work.  I complained enough to get the Mime::Lite package installed so that is making life a lot easier.  Thanks for your help!